# Django - Saving Facebook Information to database from social-registration

Tags: python, django

So I am fairly new to the whole django / python environment.  I have successfully installed the social-registration app with my django application.  Users are able to sign in with facebook and it creates a record for a user in the auth_user table and into my app_customuser table but it does not save the email, first name, last name etc.

What I was wondering is where in the structure of the application should I be looking to place the code that takes the facebook information and saves the data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

social-registration seems to be a bit simplistic; it's documentation definitely is. It's possible you can subclass the backends or potentially create your own backends based on those to store the additional fields, but that feels clunky even saying it.

It's probably not what you want to hear, but [django-socialauth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#readme) is much more widely used and better documented. It actually provides signals that you can hook into to save additional user data out of the box: http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html

Answer (score 0):

Django Facebook sounds exactly like what you are looking for
https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook

Stores
username, email, gender, birthday, about me, website, and optionally likes and friends

Very mature app, runs thousands of registrations daily on our site.